# SQL: long varchar and impact on peformance

Tags: sql, performance, long-integer, varchar

I am working with a database which is very slow. We use ASP.NET to access/populate the database. I am new to the database and I found that some of the thing are not properly done. I want to get a more knowledgeable opinion about these.

In our database varchar(255) has been used for almost all character type fields that includes zip_codes, text_ids, name ,address and phone numbers. There are about 60 of them in one table and some of them are used in comparison as well. My question is how much of a drag that is on performance? Should I change it or leave it as it is. I am esp looking for an answer that can highlight the performance issue.

**Edit:** So I think I need to work on connection rather than varchar. Can someone post answer to my question [Can I use connection pooling with SQLDatasource?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6928412/777982). It takes about 20 sec to login and after that it becomes acceptable but still slow. Database and Application are on same machine.

Comment: did you set index keys? Which storage engine do you use?

Comment: there is index only on primary key, it was from before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave as it is. There should be no problems with this definition (at least as long as the total record size doesn't exceed 8KB on MS SQL Server). Your problem is very likely related to your queries and thus implicitly to index definition and usage.

As you don't have any indexes besides the primary key ones, you should check your slow running queries and add indexes to the filter fields in your `WHERE` clause. You might want to consider the following compilation of tips regarding SQL Server performance:

[SQL Server Performance Tips and Guidelines](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/SQLServerTipsGuidelines.aspx)

Comment: Adding a note: According to the link in your answer, I should decrease the width of the column and put indexes on them, since I will be using some in WHERE clause. Making the width smaller makes the indexes efficient I guess.

Answer (score 2):

Do not worry about this. First you need to look at indexing. Next you need to look at tuning the particular long-running queries you have. Poor query writing is in my experience one of the most common causes of poor performance. But is sounds like you have basically no indexing so that must come first.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the `varchar` fields is less of an issue than using them for numerics like zip codes, phone numbers, etc.

Numerics take up a **LOT** less space than a string.  For instance:

`28245` as a `smallint` takes **2 bytes**

`'25245'` as a `varchar(255)` takes (5 bytes for data) + (2 bytes to store length) = **7 bytes**

You also will have weird issues with sorting since strings sort differently than numerics.

That being said, there's no performance difference between `varchar(20)` and `varchar(255)`.  Varchar is varchar is varchar and the only difference is the LIMIT of the space they can take in the field.

Comment: Do not store postal codes as numeric! They are not always only numbers in all countries!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a HUGE amount of data in this table I wouldn't think the field type will be impacting performance. Whenever I'm asked to look at improving the performance of a database I can usually make a big impact by improving the queries that access the data and create better indexes on the data that is already there.

Also, is the database and the website running on the same server or could there be a slow connection in between that's causing a delay?

Comment: both on same PC and no HTTP involved. I think connection could be one big problem. We use SQLDatasource and i think it does not support connection pooling. Should we change to ADO.NET?